RankingMetrics in Pyspark not working as expected
Hi I have a pyspark df like this.
 ('recs', 'array<string>'),
 ('model_pred_score', 'array<double>'),
 ('ground_truth_score', 'array<double>'),
 ('model_ranked_items', 'array<string>'),
 ('actual_ranked_items', 'array<string>')]

Where recs have the list of item which are recommended to the customer of size n, it'll have both relevant and irrelevant items recommended to customer.
model_pred_score is predicted score by model which is int and ground_truth_score is float which is calculated based on interaction, it can have 0 as well if cust has not interacted to item at all.
Now I have sorted recs, which will get us model_ranked_items and actual_ranked_items which are ranked items based on their score. They all will be of equal size of recs array column
Now I want to calculate NDCG and Precision for this items, so I'm using RankingMetrics library in python like this.
predictions_and_labels_rdd = df_grp.rdd.map(lambda row: (row["model_ranked_items"], row["actual_ranked_items"]))
ranking_metrics = RankingMetrics(predictions_and_labels_rdd)

ranking_metrics.ndcgAt(10)
ranking_metrics.precisionAt(10)

I don't know what I'm missing here but I'm always getting 1 for all the metrics. I also added relevance column later on for ndcg but still I'm getting 1 for all the metrics.
Should I not add irrelevant items to ground_truth_set?

So in the ground truth set we just need to keep k num of items while sending it to RankingMetrics. I assumed that would be automatically handled by the library but it's not.
